# Where to learn SQL Server Service Broker?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

Are there any good resources to learn Service Broker?
I'm looking for a newbie-friendly guide.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some online articles:

- [An Introduction to SQL Server Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [Service Broker Tutorials](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

I myself host a few articles:

- [Reusing Conversations](http://rusanu.com/2007/04/25/reusing-conversations/)
- [Writing Service Broker Procedures](http://rusanu.com/2006/10/16/writing-service-broker-procedures/)
- [Troubleshooting Conversations](http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/)

And there are several introduction level practical examples:

- [Centralized Asynchronous Auditing with Service Broker](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/centralized-asynchronous-auditing-with-service-broker)
- [Service Broker Foundations Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/service-broker-foundations-workbench/)
- [Using Service Broker instead of Replication](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/using-service-broker-instead-of-replication/)
- [Introducing Distributed Messaging using Service Broker in SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11795/Introducing-Distributed-Messaging-using-Service-Br)
- [Building the MSDN Aggregation System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163586.aspx)

Comment: @clarityforce - Remus has shared great links, however make sure you want to try out what you are learning. Its easy to read on SSB, but to get hold on it, one has to implement. All the best.

Comment: @ShyamViking Please don't post comments as answers.  I realize you don't have the ability to post comments yet, but it's very easy to earn the rep needed for that by posting quality answers and questions, cleaning up posts with suggested edits, etc.

Answer (score 5):

A good place to start could be [Getting Started (Service Broker)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522887%28SQL.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Also, to add to the list, once you've gone through those articles, try running the downloadable chapter-by-chapter examples in this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Server-Service-Broker-Books-Professionals/dp/1590599993](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590599993)

(can download the sql scripts and example c# projects from the publisher's web site, but 90% of the explanation is in the actual book).  The best way to get started is often to build some stuff.